# Reset a form but save one value from it

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

My app is composed from a form, RangePicker has a default value.

```js
 form.setFieldsValue({
    Picker: [moment("2020-03-09 13:00"), moment("2020-03-27 13:17")]
  });
```

I want, when i will click on submit, to reset the form, but to save only this value what set the default value of Range Picker:
`Picker: [moment("2020-03-09 13:00"), moment("2020-03-27 13:17")]`. Every time when i will click the `submit` button, to reset all values but to keep the above one. How to do this?  link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/form-methods-ant-design-demo-hzgg7

Answer (score 1):

```js
form.resetFields(['note']);
```

You can specify the fields that you want to reset as a parameter of the function `resetFields`. I added as an example only note, you can add the rest of them.